# syntax error for manage.py migration error in django

Tags: django, ubuntu-16.04

when I try to make migration it shows me an error:

```
File "manage.py", line 10
  except ImportError:
       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[image]

Comment: Please also include the content of `manage.py` file

Comment: Seems you aren't in Virtual ENV.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `make` command on `manage.py` file.

Just try the command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Comment: After a certain rep level (3K+ I think) there are no additional points to be had for editing. Editors such as myself improve posts because we want to improve the material here for the community - our way of paying back for the help we've received in the past.